# Process ID of http request, installer

Tags: winapi, http, process, installation, windows-installer

I am trying to find out if any http requests are made during installation of an msi package.  It appears to me that the process under which the http request is made shares no lineage with the process under which the installer executes.

For example, I install an app that makes http calls during installation.  Using SysInternals process monitor, I see the process created when the install kicks off.  Using MS NetworkMonitor I can see the process used to generate the http request.  Filtering in Process Monitor after the fact shows that there is no relationship between the http process, and the install process.

I am thinking that somehow the OS says to use a new process whenever an http request is made.  My most important requirement is that I be able to relate one to the other, in order to definitively say "This app installation called these http resources during install".  So I don't have to have a perfect understanding of how it all works under the covers, but, I am at a standstill right now.  I've concluded that there is no way to relate the two.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, let's assume that `msiexec.exe` invokes a helper and that helper invokes whatever is causing the HTTP traffic. Right after the first helper spawns the child it kills itself. This process is too short-lived to normally see the relationships here.

Enter the "Process Tree" feature of Process Monitor. Keep Process Monitor running without any filters on process events. After you are done you can then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to see the Process Tree (see below).

[image: Process Tree feature]

The grayed icons tell you the process is not active anymore. Furthermore the last column is the end time of the process. But best of all you can see which process created which other process from this, even for very very short-lived processes.

Mark Russinovich, author of Process Monitor and its predecessors, [demonstrated this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/SIA302) at TechEd about a month ago.

Although this may not answer the question entirely, it should get you going in the right direction. After all Process Monitor also includes network activity filtering (albeit crude, compared to Network Monitor and Wireshark :)).

btw: the green bar in the above screenshot is the "timeline" where you can see the runtime of the process in relation to other processes. Very nifty.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a custom action for making web requests? Windows Installer Service Process runs custom actions in a separate instance of MSIEXEC than your main set-up instance.

More information here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/03/02/384088.aspx